# Typo in the docs for /me

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, documentation

[The doc](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) says:

> Returns the user associated with the passed auth_token.
>
> This method returns a user.

It should say "access_token" instead of "auth_token".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.